# Как через python добавлять новый ключ в json, а не заменять

Tags: python, json

У меня есть код, создающий файл `json`:

```py
with open("notverified.json", "w", encoding='utf-8') as write_file:
    data = {'test':{'тест': 'успешно', 'точно': 'да'}}
    json.dump(data, write_file, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Как сделать так, чтобы data добавлялась к тому, что уже есть в `json`, а не заменяла его? То есть чтобы при повторном использовании там было 2, 3 и тд строчки.

Answer (score 1):

Сначала прочитать файл

```py
import json

with open("notverified.json", "r") as file:
    dict_data = json.load(file)
```

Потом добавить в словарь то, что нужно

```py
dict_data['test2'] = {'тест': 'успешно', 'точно': 'да'}
```

И записать по новой

```py
with open("notverified.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(dict_data, file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4))
```

Кодировку для `utf8` можно не указывать, она идет по умолчанию.

Есть еще варианты дописывать, перемещая курсор при чтении файла, но данные способы не стабильны и добавят головной боли.

Comment: два момента:
1)кодировка не идёт по умолчанию, нужно указывать, иначе будет '�'.(это для тех кто будет искать ответ потом)
2)как сделать, чтобы test2 был на новой строке, а не через пробелы?

Comment: @Zix читайте документацию https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#the-string-type. По второму пункту вам зачем? зачем хранить новые строки? вы читаете глазами? тогда используйте `pretty printed` для меня это не интересно

Comment: @Zix добавил вам как записать красивый json, не в настроении был) бывает) а с кодировкой, они действительно идёт по умолчанию и если вы записали utf8, то и читать вы будете utf8 и её не обязательно указывать. А вот если первоначальный файл не с той кодировкой идёт, тогда да можно указать